# Canary leak (scanf("%d", num)

Tags: memory-leaks, scanf, buffer-overflow

I'm struggling with some buffer overflow exercises regarding stack canaries. Lets say in the main function we have a buffer `buf`and an integer `num`.

So inside the main function it will look something like this:

```
char buf[32] = {0};
fflush(stdout);

int num;
scanf("%d", &num)
getchar();
print("%lu", *(unsigned long *)(buf + num));
```

Is there any sort of way that the canary can get leaked through `scanf("%d", num)`? I've been doing some research online,  but the closest I've gotten is that giving a negative number in `scanf(....` may result in memory leak (leaking the canary). But I can't seem to grasp how this works

Any help in getting me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The fact that you are using `num` and not `&num` as your `scan` arguments means whatever garbage is stored in `num` will be treated as an address and fun stuff will happen (most likely segfault). If you fix this and find a way to write more data to `num` it can spill over into `buf`.

Comment: Oops! Thats a typo from my end. It is supposed to be ```&num```. Edited the question

Comment: Now find a way to get `scanf` to read more bytes than `sizeof(int)` then the extra data will spill over into `buf` if it is stored beneath it on the stack frame.